# Two divs side by side with one div absolute

Tags: html, css

So I have this html

```
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <div class="search-form"/>
  <div class="results">
     <div class="tabs"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

search-form has absolute positioning and is floated left. I want tabs to appear next to it, but at the top of the page. Note it doesn't have to be that tabs is always on the screen(fixed is not required).

Right now I have

```
.search-form {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  float: left;
}

.tabs {
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid @section-border;
  width: 70%;
  height: 3.0em;
  float: right;
  left: 31%;
  background: @tabs-background;
}
```

But this doesn't work because on larger screens the distance between tabs and the search-form expands.

How do I get it so tabs is next to search-form, fills up the rest of the page, and that the distance between tabs and search-form does not depend on screen size?

So I just realized that tabs is inside of another div, with CSS

```
.results {
  width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Jquery/JavaScript solutions acceptable?

Comment: I suggest to remove float: right from .tabs

Comment: no JS solutions. Tried moving the float right, but now tabs is on top of the form

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: http://jsbin.com/ofagoq/11/edit

The CSS:

```
.search-form {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  float: left;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: green;
  width: 70%;
  height: 3.0em;
}
```

Comment: when I do this, the tabs becomes really large, and it still doesn't move the tabs over

Comment: could be because of my html not being reflective of what I'm actually seeing- changed the question to have more accurate html

Comment: Well, the space between .search-form and .tabs is gone and the tabs have a width of 70%, could you please be more precise about how you want it to be?

Comment: well in my version, the tabs is 'over' the search form - I have a border that runs under teh tabs, and this is going over the search form

Comment: Should now meet your requirements which are "How do I get it so tabs is next to search-form, fills up the rest of the page, and that the distance between tabs and search-form does not depend on screen size?"

Comment: hmm, I copied that- it's not working - I need to set teh search-form's position because I want a button to appear at the bottom of the page.

Comment: like I did what you did, but at width: 100%, my tabs goes below my search form

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach using % for your widths only.  You could set max and min widths as well in %.  http://jsbin.com/upucob/1/

```
.app-wrapper {
    width:90%;
    float:left;
    margin:1em 3%;
    padding: 1em 2%;
    background: #CCC;
}

.search-form {
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 600px;
    float: left;
    background:#999;
}

.tabs {
    width: 70%;
    height: 3.0em;
    float: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    background:#888;
}



<div class="app-wrapper">

    <p>This is the outter container</p>

    <div class="search-form">

        <h3>Form goes here</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="tabs">

    <h3>Tabs</h3>

    </div>

    <div class="results">

    <h3>The Results</h3>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This method keeps the containers proportional.  You would follow the same method for your form, etc.